# Freeing memory, functions

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I am trying to free some memory that I allocated in one functions in another function. An example of this would be:

```
MusicRec * createRecord(char * title, char * artist, double fileSize, int length, char theType)
{
MusicRec * newRecord;
MusicRec * next;

newRecord = malloc(sizeof(MusicRec));
newRecord->title = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(title))+1);
strcpy(newRecord->title, title);
newRecord->artist = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(artist))+1);
strcpy(newRecord->artist, artist);
newRecord->sizeInKB = fileSize;
newRecord->lengthInSeconds = length;
newRecord->type = theType;
newRecord->next = NULL;
next = NULL;
return(next);
}
```

I have malloced memory in that function, but now i am trying to free this malloced memory in a different function such as my main function. How would i do this?

Comment: Allocating memory in one function and freeing it in another is problematic. Can you not allocate it in your Main function, pass the allocated memory to your other function, then free it again after you return to Main?

Comment: The odd thing about that function is that you declare two pointers, but you only actually use the `newRecord` pointer. Yet you return the unused pointer after setting it to `NULL`. The result is that the function always returns `NULL` and does nothing with the newly allocated memory. That function should probably return `newRecord`.

Comment: @Dour: You really meant that? How would you ever build any abstractions?

Comment: It's fine to `malloc` in one place and `free` in another place.

Comment: What if i am freeing an element of a struct, does it still work?

Comment: Yes; you can free a struct or a member of a struct in some other function as long as the other function has a copy of a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the corresponding deallocation function `free()` Remember you cannot use already deallocated memory at all.

Some points to consider:

- Better change how you allocate memory, so you can more easily change the type:

  - Was: `newRecord = malloc(sizeof(MusicRec));`
  - Should be: `newRecord = malloc(sizeof *newRecord);`
- Consider defining some helper functions for things you often do. Example (this function is often actually already defined):

  - Was: `newRecord->title = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(title))+1);strcpy(newRecord->title, title);`
  - Should be: `newRecord->title = strdup(title);`
- Never use `sizeof(char)`: It looks illiterate, because you are literally asking: How many char's do I need to save one char?

For cases it's not defined:

```
char* strdup(const char* str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char* ret = malloc(len);
    memcpy(ret, str, len);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have passed that variable as reference from another function then you can free that variable from that function using free() function; otherwise you can not free that variable from another function if you have passed by value.

Comment: Are you sure? You can pass a pointer by value to another function and then free the pointer in the other function.  It is just crucial that you don't then use the pointer again in the original function.  Similarly, you can return an allocated pointer to a calling function, and the calling function can arrange to free the pointer.  So, I don't think your statement is accurate.

Comment: I have already used this type of thing in my code and it goes to free memory from another function if you have passed reference of that pointer.

Comment: Are you saying that this code won't work: `void allocator(size_t size) { void *vp = malloc(size); releaser(vp); }` and `void releaser(void *vp) { free(vp); }`?  The pointer is passed by value from `allocator()` to `releaser()` but `releaser()` can free it.  Or are you thinking of something like `void int_alloc(size_t n) { int *data = malloc(n * sizeof(*data)); int_free(data[0]); }` where `int_free()` cannot be written to free the integer passed as an argument?